# PHP, parsing out a string from within square brackets

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, I would like to extract the string `Nickname` from this string: `to[Nickname]`.

I have tried using `preg_split()` but without success.

**Update**

> how would i make it to extract from "to[nickname]" though? the "to"
>   before the brackets is also kinda important because it identifies what
>   kind of message the user is sending

Answer (score 3):

`preg_match()` is better suited for this than `preg_split()`. Here I'm using [look-arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Positive look-behind `(?<=[[])` for a left bracket `[`. Anything that is not a right bracket one or more times `[^]]+` and a positive look-ahead for the right bracket `(?=[]])`. The `!` are my delimiters of choice.

```
<?php
    $string = "to[Nickname]";
    $pattern = "!(?<=[[])[^]]+(?=[]])!";
    preg_match($pattern,$string,$match);

    print($match[0]);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Nickname
```

**Update**

Looking at one of the other questions it looks like you also want to capture the "to" part of the phrase.

```
<?php
$string = "to[Nickname]
from[Bob]
subject[This is what the message is about]";

    $pattern = "!([^[]+)\[([^]]+)\][\n\r]+!";
    preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);

    print_r($matches);
?>
```

Which outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => to[Nickname]

            [1] => from[Bob]

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => to
            [1] => from
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Nickname
            [1] => Bob
        )

)
```

So to use the variables from this one example we can store them in an array that makes sense. Here I'll create an array called `$actions` and we'll put the `action` as the `key` and the `detail` as the `value`.

```
foreach($matches[1] as $key=>$value){
    $actions[$matches[1][$key]]=$matches[2][$key];
}
```

To use the array, you would simply loop through it for the values like this:

```
foreach($actions as $action=>$detail){
    echo $action."=".$detail."\n";
}
```

**Updated Output**

```
to=Nickname
from=Bob
```

Comment: _sad fact_ : he wanted `to[Nickname]` as output ...

Comment: I agree with @CasimiretHippolyte your updated pattern is not good.  It doesn't even match all of the key-value pairs that you wrote into the input string.  I am trying to find a solid post of yours to upvote so that you know that I am not just trying to tear you down -- but I haven't found a good one yet.  Please improve this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to extract text from within `[]` brackets

`"/\[(.*?)\]/"`

I'm not sure which `preg_match()`/`preg_match_all()` is the correct one to use here, so I'll just give you the pattern that should work and let you learn the rest by looking up the function differences.

**Update from comments**

```
preg_match("/to\[(.*?)\]/", $message, $nickname);
```

Comment: how would i make it to extract from "to[nickname]" though? the "to" before the brackets is also kinda important because it identifies what kind of message the user is sending

Comment: Well you've just added another requirement. Does the return value need to change based on the identifier like 'to' or 'from'?

Comment: @NickoMrPowersRusski If that's the case you need to provide way more information. For example should `lol|to` be matched here `lol|to[nickname]|lol` ? This is regex, you need to be **precise**

Comment: `preg_match("/to\[(.*?)\]/", $message, $nickname);` thats solved it, thanks.

Comment: Remember @mrPowers to be VERY clear when asking questions, you did not mention that the 'to' was to be selected as well.

Comment: @RUJordan next time I'll be more specific ;) sorry.

Comment: @mrPowers Did you want to mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex, some combo of strpos, or you can parse it yourself. I prefer parsing strings myself most of the time, but in PHP the fastest solution usually uses the strxxx functions. Regexes can also be fast, but they are hard to write for complex cases, hard to read, and hard to debug. Here's some code to parse your string (note it includes logic for escaping the ']' character):

```
$input = 'to[somevalue]';
$length = strlen($input);

for($start = 0; $start < $length; $start++)
{
    $char = $input[$start];

    if($char == '[')
    {
        $start++;
        break;
    }
}

$out = '';
$escaped = false;

for($i = $start; $i < $length; $i++)
{
    $char = $input[$i];

    if($char == '\\')
    {
        $escaped = true;
        continue;
    }

    if($escaped == false && $char == ']')
    {
        break;
    }

    if($escaped == true)
    {
        $escaped = false;
    }

    $out .= $char;
}

echo $out;
```

Comment: I'd rather learn regex than writing a parser for each string I've to match. But I like the diversity, nice +1.